# SESSIONES PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy aprendiendo sessiones en PHP, ya tengo mi session creada, en un login ya puedo ingresar con datos reales de una base de datos, en este caso el usuario y contraseña, en mi pagina donde ya estan registrados pongo `<?php echo $_SESSION['session_username'];?>` y me da el nombre del usuario que ingreso, todo bien, mi pregunta es:

**¿De esta manera se puede pasar una imagen, misma que se encuentra en la tabla usuarios?** o **¿Tendría que hacer algún otro tipo de consulta para poder imprimirla?.**

Comment: y la pregunta es?

Comment: @muriano OP había una etiqueta de código mal cerrada que ocultaba la pregunta en sí. Puedes verla ahora.

Comment: Guarda en la sesión un array con los datos que necesites

Comment: Amigo, en vez de intentar mostrar y guardar la imagen con $_SESSION no te convendría y sería más práctico guardarla y mostrarla con $_FILES? Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Sí que puedes utilizar `$_SESSION` para mostrar imágenes:

**Si quieres cargar la imagen des de BD**

En el catalog (sustituyendo el 1 por el ID que necesites):

```
<body>
    <img src="getImage.php?id=1" width="60" height="60" />
</body>
```

getImage.php:

**Si ya tienes la imagen en un formulario**

Primero guardas la imagen que necesites así:

```
<?php
    $filename    = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
    $destination = "upload/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"]; 
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination);
    $_SESSION['imagen'] = $destination; //Se guarda la dirección de la imagen en la variable de SESSION
```

Y finalmente mostrar la imagen dónde quieras:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<div>
  <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['imagen']; ?>" alt="picture"/>
</div>
```

Comment: La primera parte sería una respuesta si la imagen viniese de un formulario, pero parece que la imagen viene de una base de datos

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tienes razón; voy a intentar modificar mi pregunta durante el día

Answer (score 1):

> mi pregunta es si de esta manera se puede pasar una imagen misma que se encuentra en la tabla usuarios

Imaginamos que una consulta simple nos trae todos los resultados que queremos en un array:

```
SELECT id, username, email, role, image FROM users WHERE id=1
```

El array resultante podría ser una cosa así:

```
$result = array(
    'id'       => 1,
    'username' => 'myusername',
    'email'    => 'myemail@email.com',
    'role'     => 'admin',
    'image'    => '/src/images/myimage.jpg'
);
```

Es interesante (recomendable) mantener una buena estructura y ordenada las variables de sesión. Conforme avanzas en el desarrollo cada vez haces más uso de ellas y suelen aumentar su cantidad.

Un ejemplo con cierto orden sería algo así:

```
$_SESSION = array(
    'user' => array(
        'id'       => $result['id'],
        'username' => $result['username'],
        'email'    => $result['email'],
        'role'     => $result['role'],
        'image'    => $result['image'],
    ),
    'data' => array(
        'last_visit' => 9786767866,
        'theme'      => 'blue',
        //...
    ),
    //...
);
```

Solo quedaría recuperarlas donde necesites

```
$user     = $_SESSION['user'];
$data     = $_SESSION['data'];
$username = $user['username'];
$avatar   = $user['image'];
```

Y ponerlas en la vista donde necesites (He asumido que es usuario y avatar como ejemplo).

```
<ul class="inline">
    <li><?php echo $username; ?></li>
    <li><img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" alt="Avatar <?php echo $username; ?>"</li>
</ul>
```